# connect() failed (111: connection refused) while connecting to upstream, java

Tags: java, nginx, digital-ocean

I configured my server 3-4 months ago, and everything worked perfectly. But for some reason, the server (DigitalOcean - droplet) stopped to answering my request. The request was going to pending status and giving a time-out exception as a response. I decided to reload the server and it gives 502 response.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.22.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>

</html>
```

I was searching for a solution for a while but didn't find the solution. Backend - Java.
My conf:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name vplannerweddings.com www.vplannerweddings.com;

        root /var/www/vplannerweddings.com/html;

        ssl_certificate /root/namecheapconfigs/vplannerweddings_com_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/vplannerweddings_com.key;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Logs of nginx gives me:

```
2023/03/08 11:29:36 [error] 8292#8292: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.205.48.122, server: vplannerweddings.com, request: "POST /user/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/login", host: "vplannerweddings.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application was not working.